# checkbox directive using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, directive

I am trying to create a checkbox directive with angularjs.[The code is here in JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/my3yzk8b/1/)

It works fine only with ng-model and text.

But if i add ng-true-value and ng-false value, it throw error as

```
nged2angular.js:12520 Error: [ngModel:constexpr] Expected constant expression for `ngTrueValue`, but saw `bindedTrueValue`.
```

Also i need to take the ng-change controller function inside the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Well two things,

Firstly, you are passing 'checkboxChanged' function to the directive, so u need to use &ngChange in the directive scope instead of =ngChange.

Without {{}}, bindedTrueValue and bindedFalseValue will be considered as strings rather than an angular variable from controller. So, It should be changed to

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="bindedModel" ng-true-value="{{bindedTrueValue}}" ng-false-value="{{bindedFalseValue}}" ng-change="bindedChange">
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/karthikrp/pen/WwNpEg/?editors=1010) for working demo.